# Find element within another element using explicit wait

Tags: automated-testing, java, appium, android

I have the following code:

```
List<MobileElement> messages = driver.findElements (By.id ("body_bubble")); //find all messages
MobileElement lastMessage = messages.get (messages.size () - 1); //get last message

// xpath query to check if the message is delivered
String xpathDeliveryStatus = ".//*[contains(@resource-id, 'delivered_indicator') or contains(@resource-id, 'read_indicator') or contains(@resource-id, 'sent_indicator')]"; 
MobileElement deliveryStatus = lastMessage.findElement (By.xpath (xpathDeliveryStatus));
```

I want to do the same except that I want to find the `deliveryStatus` variable using explicit wait. 
So I want to find the `deliveryStatus` variable inside the `lastMessage` variable using 
 `wait.until (ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated (By.locator))`

How can I do this?

I don't want to do it using one immense Xpath. Besides, I don't even know how to find the last element with the id `body_bubble` using *Xpath*, as the number of these elements is not fixed and always changing.

***P.S.*** For example, in Python we can define `WebDriverWait` with an element in the constructor instead of driver: 
`WebDriverWait(webelement, self.timeout)`

Unfortunately, it does not work in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```java
WebElement outerElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("OTER_ELEMENT_XPATH"));
WebDriverWait waiter = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);
WebElement innerElement = waiter.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(outerElement.findElement(By.xpath("./INNER_ELEMENT_XPATH"))));
```

Comment: Thank you! Also found out that I can use something like this: `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfNestedElementsLocatedBy (lastMessage, By.xpath(xpathDeliveryStatus)));`